# Decrementing app badge when push notification received outside of app

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to make sure the push notifications in my app are always up to date, that they always reflect the current data on the server.

So an example scenario:

- I'm making an email app
- the user receives a push for a new email
- Then user deletes that email on his PC, before looking at his device.

How can I remove that push from the device and decrement the badge count?  I've tried sending a new push with a decremented badge count but that will popup a new notification when I don't want a new notification popped up.

Comment: try it with content-available : 1

Comment: I believe this is only available in iOS 7 correct?  How could I do it if my app supports iOS 6 as well?

Comment: What about sending a new push with only the new badge count in the payload? If there's no alert in the payload, it shouldn't popup a new notification.

Comment: That works!  Now the only thing to figure out is how to remove a notification if the badge count reaches 0.